# Change object property via FTL

Tags: macros, freemarker

I want to modify an object before passing it to a FTL macro.

So, I want to get something like this:

```
obj.x = "123";

<@myMacro obj />
```

I tried:

```
<#local obj.x = "123"/>
```

and

```
<#assign obj.x = "123"/>
```

and

```
<#setting obj.x = "123"/>
```

but none of these methods worked.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You can't assign values to [Freemarker's sequences](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_assign.html)

> FreeMarker template language assumes that sequences (lists, arrays, etc.) and hashes (maps, beans, etc.) are immutable, you can not write something like <#assign myObj.someProperty = 'will NOT work'> or <#assign myList[0] = 'will NOT work'>. However, adding sequences or hashes with the + operator to form another value is supported; see in the chapter about [expressions](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#exp_cheatsheet), and please note the performance consequences.

You will need to create another object and assign relevant values

Comment: Indeed, using the + operator for appending is a viable solution, ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512991/add-values-to-a-sequence

_Note: the "order" of your append (right-hand vs left-hand) will have an effect on the performances (ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512991/add-values-to-a-sequence#comment107082012_5513833). IE :_
`<#assign x = x + [ "green" ] />`
is slower than
`<#assign x = [ "green" ] + x />`