# Is there a construct to unwrap or access previously defined field in freemaker?

Tags: freemarker

I have a `ftl` file with content:

```
{
  <#-- processor_tool is an existing field -->
  "processor_tool" : {
    <#if Trigger?has_content>
     "vendor_trigger": "${VendorTrigger}"
    </#if>
   ...
  },

<#-- processor_all is new entry to the ftl file -->
 "processor_all" : {
   "timeout" : "${timeout}"
   <#-- add all fields from "processor_tool" declared above -->
 }
}
```

For the new entry, "processor_all", I want to add some new fields, and add all the fields that are present in "processor_tool" (an existing entry in the `ftl` file). Can I use some construct to unwrap the values inside "processor_tool" to "processor_all".

I could copy-paste the declarations inside "processor_tool", but this would voilate DRY and will require update at two places if there is a change in "processor_tool".

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to not repeat yourself. You could use a  [macro](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_macro.html) or you can opt to [assign](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_assign.html) keys and values to a [sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512991/add-values-to-a-sequence) and use those, or use a combination.

A small demo:

```
<#assign mySeq = {"attr1": "value1", "attr2": "value2"}>
<#assign mySeq += {"attr3": "value3"}>

<#macro myMacro myParam>
  <#list myParam as propName, propValue>
    ${propName} = ${propValue}<#sep>,</#sep>
  </#list>
</#macro>

<@myMacro myParam = mySeq/>
<@myMacro myParam = mySeq/>
```

You can try this at https://try.freemarker.apache.org/

Comment: I went through the links; don't fully understand the constructs' (just starting with Freemarker) usage in my case . Can you please add an example to your answer?

Comment: I've added a demo to my answer